# floating grid image gallery vertically

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know that you can achieve this effect using tables somehow, but is there a way to grid images floating vertically like - http://www.effektivedesign.co.uk/?

Ok so I tried this with masonry.js which works great initally, but using media queries with masonry doesn't quite work. The effect sticks if an object is resized so I bailed on it. I want the effect of masonry, but with css. Is this only done with tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make 4 div columns that have `float: left`.
Use an partitioning algorithm that divides the bunch of images in 4 groups with an approximately equal summed height.
Put the images of group 1 in the left div, images of group 2 in the second div, etc.

Comment: That sounds like a tough deal. My maths not that strong. Thanks for the help. In that case I will stick to trying to figure out the tables version.

Comment: If the arrangement of images is determined, the algorithm is very easy:
1. Add up all image heights and divide by the number of columns. This is the height of each column.
2. Start a forloop and sum the image heights. Place the image in the first column.
3. If the summed height is larger than the column height, reset the counter and start adding images in the second column.
4. If all images are placed in the columns, each column should have approximately equal summed image heights.

If the arrangement is not determined, a knapsack algorithm may do the job.